# Neo4j BatchInserter initializing Db on restart

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using Neo4j BatchInserters to insert nodes in db.I am using LuceneBatchInserterIndexProvider for indexes. I have multiple files from where i am importing the data. I want if my process break then i should be able to restart the process from next file. But whenever i restart process it creates new db in graph folder and new indexes. My initialization code look like this.

```
Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<String, String>();
config.put("neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory", "2G");
config.put("batch_import.keep_db", "true");
BatchInserter db = BatchInserters.inserter("ttl.db", config);
BatchInserterIndexProvider indexProvider = new LuceneBatchInserterIndexProvider(
                    db);
index = indexProvider.nodeIndex("ttlIndex",
                    MapUtil.stringMap("type", "exact"));
index.setCacheCapacity(URI_PROPERTY, indexCache + 1);
```

Can somebody please help here?

To provide more details. I have multiple files ( around 400) which i want to import to Neo4j.
I want to divide my process into batches. After every batch i want to restart the process.
I used neo4j batch inserter config batch_import.keep_db = "true". This does not clear the graph but after restart indexer has lost information. I have this method to check for node existence. I am sure before restart i have created node.

```
private Long getNode(String nodeUrl)
    {
        IndexHits<Long> hits = index.get(URI_PROPERTY, nodeUrl);
        if (hits.hasNext()) { // node exists
          return hits.next();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: This may sound silly, but check to make sure there isn't code somewhere that is deleting the database folder contents before you create the inserter.

Comment: To my knowledge the batch-inserter doesn't create new databases. It continues to use the existing db. For the indexes some time ago there was an issue that, if you didn't write to an index during a insert-run then the indexes were removed. But afaik this was fixed.

Comment: @Michael, You are right.. I was not shutting down my indexprovider.         
`BatchInserterIndexProvider indexProvider = new LuceneBatchInserterIndexProvider(db);
BatchInserterIndex nodeIndex  = indexProvider.nodeIndex("ttlIndex",
MapUtil.stringMap("type", "exact"));
nodeIndex.setCacheCapacity(URI_PROPERTY, 500000 + 1);

###Before i was doing this
nodeIndex.flush();
###instead of doing 
indexProvider.shutDown()`

I was flushing node index periodically but never shut down the indexprovider. If i shutdownd indexprovider and restart process. I am able to query node from node Index.